# Are there any applications of the algebraic polar decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, applications

One of the decompositions mentioned in the Wikipedia page on matrix decompositions is the algebraic polar decomposition. This factors a square complex matrix $M$ into $M = SQ$ where $S = S^T$ and $QQ^T = I$. This is similar to the usual polar decomposition, except that in the usual case $S = \overline S^T$ and $Q\overline Q^T = I$.

In a 1990 paper by Kaplansky, it is shown that this decomposition exists if and only if $M^T M$ is similar to $M M^T$, and in particular this is true for all invertible matrices.

Does this decomposition have any known applications? I guess an obstacle to applications is that the complex orthogonal matrices don't form a compact space.

Answer (score 1):

The "algebraic polar decomposition" was introduced pre-Kaplansky by Choudhury and Horn as a [A Complex Orthogonal-Symmetric Analog of the Polar Decomposition](https://doi.org/10.1137/0608019) (1987).

An application to improve the convergence of iterative algorithms has been developed in [A coupled joint eigenvalue decomposition algorithm for canonical polyadic decomposition of tensors](https://hal.science/hal-01862247/document) (2016).

> In this paper we propose a novel algorithm to compute the joint
> eigenvalue decomposition of a set of squares matrices. This problem is
> at the heart of recent direct canonical polyadic decomposition
> algorithms. Contrary to the existing approaches the proposed algorithm
> can deal equally with real or complex-valued matrices without any
> modifications. The algorithm is based on the algebraic polar
> decomposition which allows to make the optimization step directly with
> complex parameters. Furthermore, both factorization matrices are
> estimated jointly. This “coupled” approach allows us to limit the
> numerical complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for this!